# Can I apply for a Canadian visa from the US as a non-resident?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, canada

I am Indian resident, with an Indian passport. I want to visit the US and Canada. First, I'll apply for a US visa and, if I get it, I will apply for Canada visitor visa. Once the US visa is granted, I would have only 15 days before departure and  there wouldn't be enough time to apply for the Canadian visa and attend an interview at the Canadian Embassy at India; the minimum time required for an interview date is 20-30 days. I want to visit both the countries in one trip.

If I apply from India for the visitor visa to Canada, can I attend the visa interview at the Canadian Embassy or Consulate in the US?

Comment: Why would you have only 15 days before departure?

Comment: My U.S visa interview is on 4-5 Aug and marriage of my niece is on 20th Aug. That is why I have with me 15 days

Comment: Is your US visa interview on 4-5 Aug for the first one, for fingerprinting and photographs? If it's the second one which, if successful, it usually take about 2 working days before your passport would be ready for collection.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is from more than a year ago, so the answer comes late. But in case someone is in a similar situation: you can get a visa in USA, even if you are not US resident. You can apply on line and, if approved you send your passport by mail with a self addresses envelop. The whole process will take more than a week, probably two, so if you are for a short period then this will not work. Bottom line: if you can, apply in your own country. Source: we did it for my mother in law in 2015.